# Python XML file get only the sub elements that have more than one tag

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ItemList>
    <Item iID="12345" iName="absbd">
      <IList>
        <I iID="895741" iName="anbgtet" iExID="12345" Qty="1.000000">
          <BcList>
            <Bcode bID="788458" bc="122346" />
          </BcList>
        </I>
      </IList>
    </Item>
    <Item iID="45679" iName="absasdsadbd">
      <IList>
        <I iID="8589" iName="adsad" iExID="5345" Qty="1.000000">
          <BcList>
            <Bcode bID="45477" bc="457859" />
            <Bcode bID="114525" bc="445785" />
          </BcList>
        </I>
      </IList>
    </Item>
</ItemList>
```

I need to retrieve only those BcList tags that have the more than one Bcode tags

I am using python for this and so far I was able to only get the individual Bcode values. Can anyone help me with this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

xmlfilePath = 'path of xml file'

tree = ET.parse(xmlfilePath)
root = tree.getroot()


for elem in root.iter(tag='Bcode'):
    #print(elem.tag, elem.attrib)
    print(elem.attrib['bc'])
    #print(elem.attrib)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the length of `tag='BcList'` and then process

**Ex:**

```
tree = ET.parse(xmlfilePath)
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter(tag='BcList'):
    if len(elem) > 1:
        for Bcode in elem.iter(tag='Bcode'):
            print( Bcode.attrib['bc'] )
```

**Output:**

```
457859
445785
```